# "Open last closed document" shortcut for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, command, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor, shortcut

Is there a shortcut or command in VS for opening last closed document?

Many times I close a doc. and a second later I regret and want to reopen it, I'm tired of struggling to find it in the solution explorer each time over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Power Commands for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99) (which works with 2012) includes such an "undo close" command (CTR + SHIFT + Z shortcut)

Comment: I already had it installed. Indeed awesome, I'm glad the thought about this shortcut as well!